# Why these openlayers' feaures get wrong coordinates?

Tags: javascript, mysql, coordinates, openlayers, latitude-longitude

I have a bunch of markers stored in a mysql database in a table with these attributes `id`,`longitude`,`latitude`.

With an ajax query I get these rows and print to console and they're exactly equal to the ones in the db.

When I create my features with openlayers, with the longitude and latitude retrieved from the db and stored in javascript variables, I don't understand why the markers are placed to another place (they're supposed to be in Italy and they are under Africa).

The interesting thing is that if I manually insert the coordinates while creating the features they show in the right place.

Browsing the internet and trying to debug my code I found some clues.

First, it may be cause of how I store longitude and latitude in the db. I saw there's someone who says DECIMAL(10,8) for latitude and DECIMAL(11,8) for longitude but all of my coordinates are similar to lon: 9.728068 and lat: 44.106414 so i decided to use DECIMAL(7,6) for longitude and DECIMAL(8,6) for latitude.

Second, if I try to console.log the data retrieved from the db I get the right coordinates e.g. 9.728068 and 44.106414 but if I get the coordinates from the features after I created them I get different values. 
For the manually inserted coordinates, I get the exact same values, but for the other one no.

Here's a snippet of my code. It's a for loop that in this case will cicle 2 times

```
var lon = r[i]["Sensor_longitude"];  //getting longitude from success response
var lat = r[i]["Sensor_latitude"];   //getting latitude from success response
console.log(lon); //first time 9.728068, second time 9.728368
console.log(lat); //first and second time 44.106414
//using retrieved coordinates to create the feature
var areaFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lon,lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
    name: sniffer_name
});
//trying to put manually the coordinates
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([9.728068,44.106414], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
    name: sniffer_name
});

console.log(ol.proj.transform(areaFeature.getGeometry().getCoordinates(),'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326'));
console.log(ol.proj.transform(iconFeature.getGeometry().getCoordinates(),'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326'));
```

I have 2 entries in my db which have 
`lon:9.728068, lat:44.106414`
`lon:9.728368 ,lat:44.106414`
so I will make 4 markers (areaFeature and iconFeature for each entry). areaFeature has the coordinates retrieved from db and iconFeature has coordinates inserted manually.
I expected the first half of logs to be 9.728068, 44.106414 and the second one to be 9.728368, 44.106414 but instead I get this:

```
9.728068 //correct
44.106414 //correct
[9.728068, -45.893585099999996] //[correct,wrong]
[9.728068, 44.106414] //[correct,correct]
9.728368 //correct
44.106414 //correct
[9.728367999999998, -45.893585099999996] //[wrong,wrong]
[9.728068, 44.106414] //[correct,correct]
```

As you can see latitude is nearly correct (don't know why it adds so many digits after the point) but it is negative and longitude in the first case is correct but in the second one it has other digits in addition.

Comment: `9.728367999999998`is`9.728368 - 0.000000000000002` so insignificant and is probably due to the nature of floating point maths in javascript ... however, those negative latitudes, look very close to `44.106414 - 90` - does that help? (though, it's 0.000009 away from `44.106414 - 90` which is way more difference than can be accounted for by "floating point maths in javascript")

Comment: I suspect your input data is a string while OpenLayers expects numbers.  `var lon = parseFloat(r[i]["Sensor_longitude"]); 
var lat = parseFloat(r[i]["Sensor_latitude"]);`

Comment: @Mike that's it! It works also by putting + in `new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([+lon,+lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))`, thanks!

Comment: `'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'` -- Why different?